# Using jQuery to change CSS property value

Tags: jquery, css

First, I must apologise. My Javascript knowledge/experience is very basic and I have tried searching for my solution (which I *know* will be very simple) but not having much luck.

I'm trying to use jQuery so when a button (with a specific ID) is clicked it changes a CSS property value.

This is the HTML:

```
      <div id="englishbutton" class="button">
        English
      </div>
```

This is the existing CSS property I'm looking to change:

```
a:lang(en) {
  background-color: #ffdc00;
}
```

And this is what I've got:

```
$('#englishbutton').on('click',
    function(){
        $('a:lang(en)').css({
            'background-color' : '#000000',
        });
    });
```

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for your help. As suggested, I switched to using a class rather than language property and was able to get what I needed working!

Comment: Usually you dont change css values with javascript, but rather add classes to those elements, which contain the wanted css specifications
For that, you can use $("selector").toggleClass("Class") or  $("selector").addClass("Class")

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but `lang()` is a CSS pseudo function, to find the element the jQuery selector might need to be `$('a[lang="en"]').css({ ...});` using square brackets.

Comment: Remove the `{ }` in .css like `$('a:lang(en)').css('background-color' : '#000000');`

Comment: @Siva both ways are valid but your syntax is not when using `:`

Comment: Seems like toggling a class would be simpler and then have rules like `a.myActiveClass:lang(en) { background-color:#000000}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my knowledge is jquery is the novice so I won't comment on it, but you can attempt it suing vanilla javascript as well. You can simply use the classist property to add/remove or toggle the class.
For better knowledge in jQuery, you could refer to W3schools refs. They are quite comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks Sara, I switched to class and then used a show/hide jQuery which achieved what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#englishbutton').on('click',
    function(){
        $('a:lang(en)').css({
            'background-color' : '#000000',
        });
    });
```

```css
a:lang(en) {
  background-color: #ffdc00;
}
```

```html
 <div id="englishbutton" class="button">
        English
      </div>
      
       <a lang="en">English</a>
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As your code given above shows you don't have any a tag with the attribute of `lang="en"` so to make sure I have added a tag with the attribute of `lang="en"`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: *"I hope this will help"* ...  an explanation of what is different than what OP is showing and why it solves their issue would help